# getApplicationContext() returns null

Tags: java, junit, javabeans, applicationcontext

I have made a config.xml file that contains a bean and from a class I'm calling the bean.

My code is here to call the bean.

```
admin = (WebServiceOperations)getApplicationContext().getBean("webService");
```

it gives nullPointerException because method getApplicationContext() gives null.

the config file in my classpath also.

My config file is :

```
<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller" contextPath="a.b.c" />
<bean id="enrollment" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">    
    <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller" />
    <property name="defaultUri"
        value="http://dev05:8080/webService/enrol"/>
</bean>
```

and error is

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Exception in constructor: test_M (java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.gfe.services.integration.TestAdminMethodsWebService.<init>(TestAdminMethodsWebService.java:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.createTest(TestSuite.java:61)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.addTestMethod(TestSuite.java:283)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.<init>(TestSuite.java:146)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.<init>(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:69)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.buildRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:28)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:47)
at junit.framework.TestSuite$1.runTest(TestSuite.java:97)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:232)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:227)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:81)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

please help me any kind of help is appreciable. thank you.

Comment: I don't think the getBean is returning null, I think getApplicationContext is returning Null.  Can you assign it to a variable and check. Update the post with the implemetnation of getApplicationContext method.

Comment: I agree with gkamal, if the `Bean` would exist, the exception would be `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` or something like this.

Comment: yes you are right. getApplicationContext() is giving null value , please tell me how to overcome this problem